# Christofides algorithm, metric TSP, and crossing paths

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization, hamiltonian-path

It is known that an optimal solution to the metric TSP problem will be a non-crossing Hamiltonian path.

Is there a known method of reducing the Euler path on the multi graph to a Hamiltonian path which is also non-crossing (final step of christofides)?